# How to upload pdf file to parse database in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, parse-platform

I'm trying to upload a pdf file from the 'supporting files' folder to the parse database. However, when i set the 'pdfFile' in the code i get an NSException saying Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The folder “test.pdf” doesn’t exist.".

```
NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileName];

PFFile *pdfFile = [PFFile fileWithName:fileName data:pdfData];
[pdfFile saveInBackground];

PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"MatchReports"];
testObject[@"file"] = pdfFile;
[testObject saveInBackground];
```

Comment: Is there a possibility that "supporting files" folder is NOT present in the main bundle? It might be a different sub-bundle in which the folder might be present.

Comment: using breakpoints i've looked at the variables of the fileName and the pdfData and they both find values.